# Characters in the heading don't count

Tags: discussion, editing

While not logged in, I edited a question.  I got an error message saying my edit could not be saved, because it didn't change at least six characters.  But in fact it did.

Guess what??  Edits in the "Title" don't count toward the six characters!

Who knew?

Answer (score 4):

Correct, only body edits are counted toward the six character minimum for a suggested edit. We view title edits as more significant than body edits.

Also, why not just log in?

Comment: Does this answer make sense? If title edits are more significant, shouldn't they not only count, but count for more than six characters? Maybe I am misunderstanding your use of "significant"?

Comment: Presumably, because title edits are "more significant" it makes sense to be more restrictive about who can make them, and therefore not allow low-rep users to even suggest them.